# React, Firebase app getting XRH Failed Loading issue W/ Auth Sign In

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, oauth

I am working on a React/Firebase app. I do have a server that I am making API calls to (which is also connected to the same firebase DB), but using Heroku deployment to deploy my client side app.

I'm using firebase OAuth (google specifically) to log users in. I can login/logout a user in localhost, but my deployed site on heroku is giving me

```
XHR failed loading: GET "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig?key=myAPIkey".
```

when I'm attempting to log in. I've tested my deployed site in Safari and firefox as well, and still getting a failed loading issue.

GoogleAuth code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { login, authenticate, checkForAuthenticatedUser } from '../../actions/authentication';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button, Sidebar, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import googleB from '../../assets/google-logo.png';
// import LearnMore from '../../components/Learn/LearnMore';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import './GoogleAuth.css';


class GoogleAuthentication extends Component {
 static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object,
   }

 componentDidMount = () => {
  if (!this.props.userData || !this.props.userData.name) {
   this.props.checkForAuthenticatedUser();
  }
 }

  render() {
    const { userData } = this.props;
    if (userData && userData.name) {
      return (<Redirect to="/Home" />);
    }
    return (
            <div id='login'>
            <h2 className='signinheader'>Sign In with Google</h2>
            <Button id='loginbutton' onClick={this.props.login} size="massive"circular icon>
              <img style={{ width: '50px', height: '50px' }} src={googleB} alt="" />
            </Button>
          </div>

    );
  }
}

export default connect(({ userData }) => ({ userData }), { login, authenticate, checkForAuthenticatedUser })(GoogleAuthentication);
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import Auth from './components/HOC/Require_Auth';
import App from './App';
import Login from './components/GoogleAuth/GoogleAuth';
import Logout from './components/GoogleAuth/Logout';
import Home from './views/Home/index';
import Profile from './views/Profile/index';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(), applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, promiseMiddleware()));


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
   <div className='container'>
    <BrowserRouter>
     <div>
      <Route  path='/' component={App} />
       <Route exact path='/Home' component={Auth(Home)}/>
       <Route exact path='/Profile' component={Auth(Profile)}/>
       <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
       <Route path="/Logout" component={Auth(Logout)} />
     </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   </div>

  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
 );
```

and package.json

```
{
  "name": "get_connected_client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "firebase": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.71.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

My firebase app is initialized in my app.js component

Anyone have dealt with this issue before? And have a possible solution?

Comment: You are most likely missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, that means that you have probably not setup the domains properly in firebase. I want to say "redirect domain", but could be wrong.

Comment: you f'ing genius! that was it. thank you so much Borko

Comment: No problem - glad that it helped!